# Error in Open MPI run configurations with eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, mpi, openmpi

I have created a simple Open MPI project from default list ("MPI Pi C Project") using eclipse-kepler and PTP tools 7 (both latest). The project builds without any errors, and if I click on run, the output is also shown. However, when I configure project through "Run Configurations",  and then press on "run" button, it gives me this error:

"Can't open perl script "C:/Documents": No such file or directory".

I tried my best to find out the reason of this error. At least in the "Path" variable, there is no path that contains "C:/Documents".

I am working on windows xp, with cygwin installed. The perl is also installed with cygwin, and working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just checked the log, it was having this text: 

"!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Documents and Settings\Osman Khalid'. If this is not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. "

If that could be the cause, then how can I set this HOME environment variable...

Comment: Looks like your build environment does not tolerate paths with spaces. Put your project in another directory, e.g. `C:\Projects\MPI\first_project`.

Comment: thank you. My project location  was without spaces "D:\cygwin\home\mympi"

Comment: Then you probably have something else installed under the `Documents and Settings` folder. I am not aware of Open MPI using Perl, neither on Windows, nor on Unix. Could it be a problem in your Cygwin install?

Comment: Actually, the same OpenMPI program works fine in Cygwin command line environment. I am suspecting it might be a bug in eclipse. I have contacted their support and awaiting reply. Thank you for kind replies.